# Convert GeoTiff image to Python Shapely polygon geometries representing 3 dimensional triangles

Tags: python, gis, mesh, tiles, shapely

I am working on implementing the example at [Quantized-Mesh-Tile](https://quantized-mesh-tile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/terraintile.html#quantized_mesh_tile.terrain.TerrainTile) on my own data sets which are in .Tif (Digital Elevation Models) format.

According to the module, it accept input data in one of this fomats:-

```
A list of shapely polygon geometries representing 3 dimensional triangles.
    or
A list of WKT or WKB Polygons representing 3 dimensional triangles.
    or
A list of triplet of vertices using the following structure:
    ``(((lon0/lat0/height0),(...),(lon2,lat2,height2)),(...))``
```

How to I convert my .Tif image to the shapely polygon geometries representing 3 dimensional triangles? Or any of the options above.